# Error on on() function creating a Reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

just approaching the use of ngrx and I have an unhandled error that I can't solve, try to search but nothing, here is the error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwNAL.png)

It tells me that I have to enter 4 arguments but wherever I'll search that is the correct syntax with another alternative, does anyone know what the problem is? thank you

Here is the reducer's page, I'll post the action page too, tell me if you have some news

```js
import { createReducer, on, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as ProvaActions from './prova.actions';
import { ProvaState } from './prova.model';


export const initialState: ProvaState = {
    user: {},
    error: false
}

const provaReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(ProvaActions.editProvaSuccess, (state, action ) => ({user: action.user , error: false })),
    on(ProvaActions.editProvaFailed, (state, action ) => ({ user: {}, error: true }))
);
  
export function reducer(state: ProvaState | undefined, action: Action) {
    return provaReducer(state, action);
  }
```

```js
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';


export const editProva = createAction(
    '[Prova] Edit',
    props<{user: any}>() //payload, parametri che passo
)

export const editProvaSuccess = createAction(
    '[Prova] Edit Success',
    props<{user: any}>()
)

export const editProvaFailed = createAction(
    '[Prova] Edit Failure')
```

```js
export interface ProvaState {
    user: any,
    error: boolean;
}
```

Comment: can you add a stackblitz example please?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dbxveh?file=prova.reducers.ts

Comment: here it is, the error still remain

Comment: where do you see the error? I am not seeing any errors

Comment: in the prova.reducers.ts page, the on function in the createReducer is underlined with red and there is the error expected 4 but 2 have

Comment: if i enter in the stackblitz project linked after compiling it gives me the error

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. This was how I solved it.

- Make sure you have Typescript 4.1.5 installed.
- Change your VSCode Workspace Typescript version (in the bottom toolbar on the right) to 4.1.5.

Comment: Thank you so much, i’ll try it and tell you if solved

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
const provaReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(ProvaActions.editProvaSuccess, (state, action ) => ({user: action.user , error: false })),
    on(ProvaActions.editProvaFailed, (state, action ) => ({ user: {}, error: true }))
);
```

to

```
const provaReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(ProvaActions.editProvaSuccess, (state, action ) => { return {user: action.user , error: false }}),
    on(ProvaActions.editProvaFailed, (state, action ) => {return { user: {}, error: true }})
);
```

side note,

```
on(ProvaActions.editProvaFailed, (state, action ) => ({ user: {}, error: true }))
```

Should be

```
on(ProvaActions.editProvaFailed, (state) => ({ user: {}, error: true }))
```

The way you defined `export const editProvaFailed = createAction('[Prova] Edit Failure')`, without props, means that you do not pass the action through

Comment: thank's but the error is on number of arguments passed in the on() function cause it tells me that i have to enter 4 arguments but 2 are obtained, don't know why

Comment: adding the return it doesn't change anything